# Web page loaded by PhantomJS thinks Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, geb

I am using Geb to do functional testing for my site.  I want to use a headless browser so I chose PhantomJS.  The web site seems to load as if javascript is disabled.  The problem is that my site is based on javascript and Geb is not able to detect the normal elements such as buttons that are on the site that I need to test.  You can see JS is clearly enabled.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
PhantomJSDriver desktopDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities)
desktopDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768))
```

And I can prove this from the log output...

```
[INFO  - 2015-12-13T22:09:46.926Z] Session [389fe0a0-a1e6-11e5-89cc-4322be01a995] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.7","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1.0","platform":"mac-unknown-32bit",
"javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
```

When I dump the page source from phantomJS, it shows the following markup:

```
</body></html>
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><title>Login</title></head>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">

<!-- Notify user that they must perform an action if Javascript is disabled. -->
<noscript>
    &lt;p&gt;
    &lt;strong&gt;Note:&lt;/strong&gt; Since your browser does not support      Javascript, 
        you must press the continue button once to proceed.
    &lt;/p&gt;
</noscript>

<form action="https://www.myaction.com” method="post">

    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name=“request” value="">
    </div>

    <!-- Only provide a Continue button if Javascript is not enabled. -->
    <noscript>
        &lt;div&gt;
        &lt;input type="submit" value="Continue"/&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
    </noscript>

</form>
```

By the way, the same tests work fine in both the Firefox and Chrome browser drivers.

Does anyone know of any issues where this sort of thing happens with PhantomJS?

Comment: The existence of a `<noscript>` element doesn't mean that it doesn't support JavaScript. What's the problem? Have you taken a screenshot to see if there is actually a problem?

Comment: @Artjom B. Thanks for reminding me.  I forgot to mention that the screenshot file is 0kb so there is nothing in it.  The screenshots do work properly for other errors that may occur.  The problem is that my inputs that accept username and password (and the submit button for the form) are completely missing.  So the login test fails because the elements aren't there.

Comment: You have HTML after the closing `</html>` tag. This can only lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't know what might fix this, because the site is behaving really badly, but you can try sending a common user agents string like the one from Chrome or Firefox. What version of PhantomJS do you use?

Comment: @LeeTaylor - You raised a great point and I am wondering if malformed </html> is actually causing the issue.  Unfortunately the login is developed by a different group and I don't have access to the source.

Comment: @Artjom I will try your suggestion and see if changing the user agents will work.

Comment: @Barry I'd suggest talking to that group. If your HTML is plain wrong then you can't expect it to work properly.